# Insert with multiple selects

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-insert, insert-select

I have a SQL request that return some ora-01427 error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

```
INSERT INTO my_table (value0, value1, value2, value3) 
        VALUES((SELECT MAX(value0) FROM my_table), '5', (SELECT DISTINCT(value2) FROM another_table), '8');
```

The thing is, I need two hard-coded values, I need a value from a select that returns only one row, and I want to do that for each row returned by a second select.

I feel like this query would work if only I had only one select. Is there a way to do multiple SELECT inside an INSERT ? What would be the syntax ?

EDIT : my_table and some_table are actually the same table, sorry for not being clear in the first place, actually, I need value0 to be unique so it needs to retrieve the biggest id each time, not just before the insertion but every time a new row is inserted.

Comment: It's the second sub-select that returns more than one row. Do insert ... select instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch to INSERT/SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (value0, value1, value2, value3) 
SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT MAX(value0) FROM some_table), '5', value2, '8'
FROM another_table;
```

To answer your comment on jarlh's post: "*What if some_table = my_table and value0 needs to be incremented each time a value is inserted ?*"

```
INSERT INTO my_table (value0, value1, value2, value3) 
SELECT
   (SELECT MAX(value0) FROM my_table) 
     + ROWNUM -- ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever you need)
  ,'5'
  ,value2
  ,'8'
FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT value2
    FROM another_table
  ) dt
```

Edit:

I switched to `ROWNUM`, but this is proprietary syntax. Oracle also supports Standard SQL's ROW_NUMBER and it should be working as-is, too.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I may have trouble understanding the OVER keyworld.
Anyway, I tryied and get an id not unique error. Is there a way to get the value at execution ?

Comment: All right, your method was a good trail to follow. Using the rownumber keyword instead of funciton worked great!

Comment: If you replace "ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY whatever you need)" by "rownum" I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @Vdolez: switched to `ROWNUM`, but the `ROW_NUMBER` syntax should also work (you must have done something else if it failed...)

Comment: Is it possible that the function is only executed before the treatment whereas the keyworld match the number of occurence during treatment ?

Comment: @Vdolez:  When you run the `SELECT` without the `INSERT` you will see the actual data. Assuming this is not the actual query something else might cause this error.

Answer (score 3):

You can covert these two queries to a single one by cross joining the query from `some_table` with the results of `anoter_table`. The hard coded literal could also be selected.

Additionally, note that for inserting a `select` result you don't need the `values` keyword:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (value0, value1, value2, value3) 
SELECT      DISTINCT max_value_0, '5', value2, '8'
FROM        another_table
CROSS JOIN  (SELECT MAX(value0) AS max_value_0
             FROM some_table) t
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't try. I felt there was an 'easier' solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do INSERT with SELECT instead:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (value0, value1, value2, value3)
    SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT MAX(value0) FROM some_table), 5, value2, 8
    FROM another_table
```

Comment: What if some_table = my_table and value0 needs to be incremented each time a value is inserted ?

Comment: Ok, so my_table = some_table.
Value0 is an ID and must be unique.
Each time a value is inserted in my_table, I need SELECT MAX(value0) to be updated.